# Loop optimization for generating sub-strings

Tags: java, file, for-loop, bufferedreader, bufferedwriter

This is the loop in my code that I am trying to optimize. It takes the arg[0] as a file name and makes substrings but not all substrings, **for example, mice as mice, ice, ce ,e**. That is what `getAllUniqueSubset()` does.

```
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]));
    new File("./indexof"+args[0]).mkdirs();
    BufferedWriter out = null;
    SubString sub = new SubString();

    String s;

    while ((s = in.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] list = s.split(" ");
        for(int i=0;i<list.length;i++){
            ArrayList<String> substrings = sub.getAllUniqueSubset(list[i].replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", "").toLowerCase());

            for(String sb:substrings){

                out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("./indexof"+args[0].toLowerCase()+"/"+sb.charAt(0)+".txt",true));

                out.write(sb);
                out.write(" ");
                out.write(Integer.toString(lineNumber));
                out.newLine();
                out.flush();
            }   
        }
        lineNumber++;

    }

    in.close();
    out.close();
```

This bit of code gets the substrings i've mentioned above from a file and sorts into each file of the charAt(0).txt

this takes about 70000ms to take care of a 500kb file

but when the file gets large enough like 500mb, the time gets so big

so my questions are

- Is there a better way to get the substrings as i want in to a file?
- Or is there a way to speed up the BufferedReader?

Comment: I think it will be better to do `String[] list = s.toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^a-z ]", "").split(" ")` instead of doing that for each `String` in the array.

Comment: Also, you're not closing the `BufferedWriter` after you're done with it.

Comment: oh sorry about that. there is a close() after the code. I'll edit it

Comment: You need to close the writer inside the inner for loop, since you're opening a new file writer every iteration.

Comment: How many files does your 500kB input produce? What's their total size?

Comment: @JiriTousek it takes about 3mb in size since its about n(n+1)/2? or so

Comment: It is the frequent open/close that causes this overly long processing time. Since you have only 26 output files, keep them open all the time.

Comment: @laune Thank you very much. Its been a great help!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This keeps BufferedWriters open. Removed the flush. Added a biggish buffer size. - It is a little more efficient with the processing of a line.

```
   BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]));
   new File("./indexof"+args[0]).mkdirs();
   BufferedWriter[] outs = new BufferedWriter[26];
   SubString sub = new SubString();
   String s;
   int lineNumber = 1;
   while( (s = in.readLine()) != null ){
       s = s.replaceAll("[^\\sa-zA-Z]", "").toLowerCase();
       String[] list = s.split("\\s+");
       for( String sl: list ){
           ArrayList<String> substrings = sub.getAllUniqueSubset(sl);
           for( String sb: substrings ){
               BufferedWriter out = outs[sb.charAt(0)-'a'];
               if( out == null ){
                   out = outs[sb.charAt(0)-'a'] =
                   new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("./indexof"+args[0]+"/"+sb.charAt(0)+".txt",true), 1024*16);
               }
               out.write(sb);
               out.write(" ");
               out.write(Integer.toString(lineNumber));
               out.newLine();
           }   
       }
       lineNumber++;
   }
   in.close();
   for( BufferedWriter out: outs ){
       if( out != null ) out.close();
   }
```

**Edit** Tested with http://textfiles.com/programming/bourne1.txt, which is a 
597768 bytes textfile. Completes in 1 (one) second.

Comment: Wow. I never expected this to be so fast.. I have an additional question. Is there a way to open files quickly? like the buffered writer? Maybe not needed since there is only String and (Int)String?

Comment: Opening a file typically consists of allocating a buffer and an operating system call. You can't exert much influence on one or the other. But try to avoid repeated open/close operations since the OS needs to do some work, including actual i/o on a device for reading and writing blocks on the data file or the file system data - even if there's a cache it means moving data back and forth.